# onenote api started returning Internal Server Error

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, onenote

I'm the author of the Windows Phone app "Pinmore for Onenote".
I recently noticed the app has developed a bug (no changes to the app) and that calls to the OneNote api are returning an Internal Server error.

I've also just run the example code provided here https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISampleWinUniversal

And this is also returning an Internal Server error.

This has been happening for a few days now.  Nothing has changed on my app, which has been working for months, and I would expect the example code to work.

This is a set of response headers when trying to run the universal app example at https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISampleWinUniversal

```
+       Headers {Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-CorrelationId: ab1c9cdd-3db8-4dc1-afba-48774441ffba
X-UserSessionId: ab1c9cdd-3db8-4dc1-afba-48774441ffba
X-OfficeFE: OneNoteServiceFrontEnd_IN_0
X-OfficeVersion: 16.0.6023.1561
X-OfficeCluster: neu-www.onenote.com
P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR ADMa DEV CONi TELi CUR PSA PSD TAI IVDi OUR SAMi BUS DEM NAV STA UNI COM INT PHY ONL FIN PUR"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
OData-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 28 Jul 2015 10:26:35 GMT
Connection: close
}   System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpResponseHeaders
```

And this is a set when trying to run my app, Pinmore for OneNote. (Note, I've had multiple reports of the app suddenly stopping working for people recently)

```
+       Headers {Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-CorrelationId: ac66e037-776b-4c39-b46c-ea85c501cdab
X-UserSessionId: ac66e037-776b-4c39-b46c-ea85c501cdab
X-OfficeFE: OneNoteServiceFrontEnd_IN_5
X-OfficeVersion: 16.0.6023.1561
X-OfficeCluster: neu-www.onenote.com
P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR ADMa DEV CONi TELi CUR PSA PSD TAI IVDi OUR SAMi BUS DEM NAV STA UNI COM INT PHY ONL FIN PUR"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
OData-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 28 Jul 2015 10:31:26 GMT
Connection: close
}   System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpResponseHeaders
```

Stuart

Comment: Can you paste a set of response headers from a failing call, so we can diagnose please?

Comment: But actually, cant you reproduce the issue with the sample universal app code that I posted the github link to? I downloaded that, built it unmodified and ran in the emulator and it gave exactly the same error.

Comment: We'll try, but I wanted to get your correlation ids in case it works for us.

Comment: Gareth, I've added the response headers you requested in the original post, as they are too long for comments.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because this is a support issue you'd have to take up with OneNote directly. Also see [*Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've identified, this is a problem on our end. We are deploying a fix right now that we expect will remedy this problem for you. Our deployments take a couple of hours and are rolling in nature so it may be intermittent for the next while.

Comment: Thanks for this, it fixed the problem.

Comment: A quick question - this question has been closed as off-topic because it's a customer service question.  Can you please tell me where I should raise any future problems like this with the onenote API, if not here?